# Tensorflow-io import returns error "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0, avx

I am trying to `import tensorflow-io` package in my Docker Anaconda container, but am I receiving errors "**Illegal instruction (core dumped)**" in the console, or, when I just want to import tensorflow-io, the Jupyter notebook's Kernel just dies.

I had a similar problem with TensorFlow, and I solved it by finding the wheel that is created **without AVX instructions**, as my host nor container does not support them. But I cannot find that whl file for tensorflow-io.

Just to mention, I first tried to create the TensorFlow package from the source code with **bazel**, but my VM just stopped responding and needed a soft reboot. I do not have enough resources to create the package from the source file, apparently.

I would much appreciate it if someone has a wheel of tensorflow-io to share.

```
My configuration is as follows:
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              1
Socket(s):                       8
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           44
Model name:                      Westmere E56xx/L56xx/X56xx (IBRS update)
Stepping:                        1
CPU MHz:                         2400.076
BogoMIPS:                        4800.15
Virtualization:                  VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       256 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        32 MiB
L3 cache:                        128 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX flush not necess
                                 ary, SMT disabled
Vulnerability Mds:               Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no mic
                                 rocode; SMT Host state unknown
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB condit
                                 ional, IBRS_FW, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse s
                                 se2 syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc r
                                 ep_good nopl xtopology cpuid tsc_known_freq pni
                                  pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2
                                 apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes hypervisor l
                                 ahf_lm cpuid_fault pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr
                                 _shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust a
                                 rat umip arch_capabilities
```

Comment: I saw pypi.org/project/tensorflow-io/#files. So, which of these whl files is without AVX instructions?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Nvidia Jetson TX1 on Python when I want to import tensorflow
and when I close the Terminal this Problem disappeared.
some times I should reboot the system.
here maybe you should reset the jupyter kernel or reboot your system.
If you want to find the .whl file for `tensorflow-io` [this](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-io/#files) link contains tensorflow-io package.